# How to see Leading zero in CSV after converting from Excel

Tags: excel-2013

I have a columns in excel like this.

Id
001234567

After I converting to CSV I could not see 001234567 in instead I`m seeing 1234567.but in the excel sheet I will able to see with zeros and also If i open the CSV file and notepad also I`m seeing but not when I open with excel.

could you please help me with this.

FYI:I ma using Excel 2013

Thanks,
Sowjanya

Comment: Try changing the cell format to text before you export

Comment: The original excel has the Text format after converting to CSV it is changing as general

Answer (score 0):

By opening the file in Excel you are triggering automatic coercion of what look like numbers into numbers and along with that the dropping of leading zeros.

If you wish to retain the leading zeros (ie the text formatting) *import* the .csv (DATA > Get External Data, From Text) and at Step 3 of 3 in the import process ensure that *Column data format* of Text is selected for the relevant column or columns.